# PostgreSQL - MAX value for every user

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table

```
User | Phone | Value
Peter | 0 | 1
Peter | 456 | 2
Peter | 456 | 3
Paul | 456 | 7 
Paul | 789 | 10
```

I want to select `MAX` value for every user, than it also lower than a tresshold

For tresshold 8, I want result to be

```
Peter | 456 | 3
Paul | 456 | 7
```

I have tried the GROUP BY with HAVING, but I am getting

```
column "phone" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Similar query logic works in MySQL, but I am not quite sure how to operate with GROUP BY in PostgreSQL. I dont want to GROUP BY phone.

Comment: Not using `group by` is invalid SQL and will be rejected by every other DBMS. It only "works" in MySQL because MySQL prefers to return random ("indeterminate") results rather than rejecting invalid statements: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I have results from "juergen d" solution, I came up with this which gives me the same results faster

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(user) user, phone, value
FROM table
WHERE value < 8
ORDER BY user, value DESC;
```

Comment: you should accept this one as it is the most performant solution

Comment: Remark: Might be best performing, but it's another proprietary syntax no other DBMS supports. On the other hand Standard SQL's  `RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER` is supported by almost all DBMSes (besides MySQL).

Answer (score 2):

```
select t1.*
from your_table t1
join
(
    select user, max(value) as max_value
    from your_table
    where value < 8
    group by user
) t2 on t1.user = t2.user and t1.value = t2.max_value
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use a ranking function:

```
select * from 
(
select *, RANK() OVER (partition by [user] ORDER BY t.value desc ) as value_rank from test_table as t
where t.value < 8
) as t1
where value_rank = 1
```